configuration error: /mingw64/share/gnucobol/config\default.conf: No such file or directory
after getting gnucobol set up on my computer I made a simple hello world program, found the necessary command to build it, and... got the error mentioned in the title, I added gnucobol to my PATH variable and the filepath mentioned in the title does exist, what's the issue? I have restated my computer multiple times and verified that the file does exist, I also have this makefile if that helps anything
    # Compiler
COBC = cobc

# Flags
COBFLAGS = -x -o

# Program name
PROGRAM = CrownXVanguard

# Source file
SRC = main.cbl

# Default target
all: $(PROGRAM)

# Build the program
$(PROGRAM): $(SRC)
    $(COBC) $(COBFLAGS) $(PROGRAM) $(SRC)

# Clean target
clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM)

# Phony targets
.PHONY: all clean


This question is similar to: How to fix vscode GnuCOBOL setup "configuration error: default.conf: No such file or directory". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've already tried most of those solutions and none worked
